# In Suicide Squad, did this character die and come back to life?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

In *Suicide Squad*,

> the Joker

is seemingly killed in an explosive helicopter crash.

Later on,

> Harley Quinn

asks Enchantress to bring this character back, which she agrees to,

> shortly before being betrayed by Harley.

At the end of the movie,

> the Joker reveals that he's still alive.

Did this character die and get brought back to life by Enchantress, or did they manage to somehow survive the initial event? If so, do we know how?

Comment: He tends to die and come back alot, living miraculously

Comment: Related question from movies and TV [How did the Joker survive the helicopter crash?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/how-did-the-joker-survive-the-helicopter-crash)

Comment: @CLIQUEY - If you feel like copy/pasting [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142975/20774) onto the other site, feel free. I know how you all feel about books with words in.

Comment: @Valorum novelisation is not my kind of answering method but others can freely do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the film's [official novelisation](http://titanbooks.com/suicide-squad-the-official-movie-novelization-8758/). The Joker survived the helicopter crash in exactly the same way that Harley did, by jumping from it before it hit the ground.

> *Then hell plummeted from the sky in the guise of a crippled, out of
>   control Chinook helicopter that skidded across rooftops and shredded
>   its way down Ninth Street, only to careen into the bank’s facade,
>   destroying glass, stone, and mortar before its sturdy all-steel vault
>   put an abrupt stop to the aircraft.*
>
> *The copter was on fire. Nothing inside could have survived.*
>
> ***From across the way, on another rooftop, the Joker watched the flames
>   rising into the sky. He had jumped just in time. If he had waited even
>   another ten seconds, he would now be little more than ash.***

Of course, this utterly ruins [the big reveal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAXfOsGyehY&feature=youtu.be&t=23s) at the end of the film, which is presumably why they took this scene out of the shooting script.

Answer (score 3):

There is no information in the movie to know if he was dead and has been revived or if he just survived the crash.

Maybe the novelization of the script will throw some insight about it, but I doubt it, is the type of narrative tool that an author would use to keep it's audience thinking.

Comment: You are mistaken. The novelisation spells out in excruciating(ly bad) detail how the Joker survived.

Comment: AFAIK there weren't official novelisation by the time I wrote my answer

Comment: It's not a criticism of you. I was simply pointing out that your expectation that the novelisation would leave this question unanswered (to preserve the mystery of the scene) was woefully over-optimistic :-)